# How can I complete both words and WORDS?

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion, functions

I found [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/ins-completion-of-words), but mine is a bit different.

When I write code dealing with arrays or classes like `$myArray['myElement']` or `document.getElementById("myElement")`, I get annoyed because I have to use word completion a few times.  Vim's completion is helpful like `$myA<C-P>` completes `$myArray`, but then I still have to type `['$myE<C-P>']` to finish the whole WORD. I tried changing `iskeyword` to include `'[].`, but that returned too many results to sort through when I only wanted to complete words.  `d<C-X><C-L>` is helpful sometimes, but also not what I'm looking for.

How can I configure Vim to keep the default word completion to complete `d<C-P>` to `document`, and also add something, maybe `<C-X><C-W>`, to complete `d<C-X><C-W>` to `document.getElementById("myElement")`?

Comment: I think you should be able to use the answer here: [How do I complete a WORD?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/how-do-i-complete-a-word) Just change the mapping to trigger on `<C-X><C-W>` instead of overriding the existing completion keystrokes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't find that question when I looked.  I'll see if I can get that to work and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: Great, with a little modification, that does work.  I learned a bit more vimscript, and I might continue to tinker, but for now I have: `inoremap <C-X><C-W> <C-O>:call <SID>CustomKeyword(join(map([char2nr('.'),char2nr('"'),char2nr("'")]+range(char2nr('0'),char2nr('~')), 'nr2char(v:val)'), ''))<CR><C-X><C-N>`, etc.